# Creating sky HDRI from alien solar system model

Tags: rendering, camera, hdri

I have a model of a fictional solar system, and I would like to basically make an HDRI of "what the sky would look lke" on one of the planets' surfaces. The issue is that the distances are to-scale, and it's very difficult to put the camera on the surface in a way that looks good because of the distances. I've done the math and I know what the size of the closest object in the sky will be (in short, huge, 30 degrees across in the sky), and I could probably do a disappointing physically inaccurate sky, but would be really cool to use the actual model I have. (model is below)

[image]

Alternatively, if there are any online tools that would let me simulate the sky, I'd also appreciate that.